# How To Introduce a Void Method to a LINQ Query with Query Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a LINQ query which I must keep in query syntax:

```
foreach (var productId in (from batchOrder in batchOrders
    let outputFileName = GetUniqueFileName(batchOrder)
    let ssisResult = SendToSsis(productId, outputFileName)
    where ssisResult == 0))
{
    // Does something here
}
```

And I need to introduce a new operational call without leaving the bounds of the query. If the method I'm calling returns a boolean value, I can add it with the `let` keyword:

```
foreach (var productId in (from batchOrder in batchOrders
    let outputFileName = GetUniqueFileName(batchOrder)
    let ssisResult = SendToSsis(productId, outputFileName)
    // The next line is the new call
    let trackingFiles = OutputTrackingFiles(batchOrder)
    where ssisResult == 0))
{
    // Does something here
}
```

But what if the `OutputTrackingFiles()` method is a void? How can I include that call, without modifications, in the query?

Comment: Think seriously before trying to do this. You're mixing the concepts of actions and querys inside QUERY SYNTAX. I would suggest you call OutputTrackingFiles inside of the foreach loop, perhaps moving the where clause into an if statement

Comment: I agree with berkeleybross. LINQ queries are *queries*, you shouldn't use it to do anything else that will alter the state of the system, especially when LINQ queries can sometimes have delayed executions. That's why methods used in LINQ queries must always return values.

Comment: @berkeleybross and SF Lee Agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't. But you can wrap it in a delegate that does return something.

```
...
let trackingFiles = new Func<bool>(() => { OutputTrackingFiles(batchOrder); return true; })()
...
```

If you do this a lot, a helper method will make this more concise:

```
...
let trackingFiles = Execute(() => OutputTrackingFiles(batchOrder))
...

private static bool Execute(Action action)
{
    action();
    return true;
}
```

or:

```
...
let trackingFiles = Execute(OutputTrackingFiles, batchOrder)
...

private static bool Execute<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)
{
    action(arg);
    return true;
}
```

But of course this only works for one argument -- you'd have to have a separate method for each number of arguments you want to support.

Comment: Also: I agree with all the comments on the OP. Putting state change operations in LINQ usually a bad idea (but SO tempting!).